# Running TestNG test case from ANT giving DomSource cannot be proccesed?

Tags: dom, ant, jar, testng, saxon

I have an ant task which runs testNG testCase.But while running it is showing error like below one

```
 [testng] Error 
 [testng]   DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon8-dom.jar is on the classpath
 [testng] [GeneralXMLOutput] [Error] DOMSource cannot be processed: check that saxon8- dom.jar is on the classpath
```

My lib folder is having jdom-0.7.jar, saxon-8.7.jar, SaxonLiasion.jar which is related with xml. Is it a jar file dependency conflict?

How to resolve this error?

ANT TASK

```
 <target name="runTests" depends="compile">
    <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${build.dir}">
        <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
    </testng>
</target>
```

i have used javax.xml.transform.Transformer api from rt.jar in some other classes And saxon is also having Transformer Api.(Whethter that creates a problem?)

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is pretty clear: check that saxon8-dom is on the classpath. From what you have said, it isn't.

But Saxon 8.7 is an ancient release anyway, the current version is 9.4. Recent releases include the DOM support in the main JAR file - the reason it was kept separate in the past was because DOM API's changed in an incompatible way between JDK 1.4 and JDK 1.5, and this problem disappeared when Saxon dropped support for JDK 1.4.